# Shortcut for Range[]?

Tags: syntax, keyboard

I use  `Range` a lot. Is there any syntactic shortcut for it, or do you always have to spell it out?

Comment: You could use the [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) to define a custom shortcurt for it.

Comment: I think, William means a custom alias using the esc keys. Or you could even define your own shorthand function. `R=Range;`. You could also try typing R and then pressing Command+(Shift)+K (or the equivalent windows keys) for autocompletion and templates. Yet another option may be to check out Halirutan's IntelliJIdea plugin.

Comment: Why don't you try `r = Range;`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a nicer layout for  `Range` you could try the Notation package:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notation is a bit picky about the definition code of your notation. It has to go manually via its templates. That's why I used a picture above. The following code should work when copied:

```
<< Notation`

CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[
    RowBox[{"InfixNotation", "[", 
       RowBox[{
          TemplateBox[{"\[TripleDot]"},
            "NotationTemplateTag"], ",", "Range"}], "]"}]], "Input"]
```

After executing those two lines, a third one will appear which must be executed as well. After that you can use the `\[TripleDot]` character to define ranges:

```
5 \[TripleDot] 9
```

> {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

If you just want shorter code you can define:

```
r = Range;
r@5
r[3, 9, 2]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>
> {3, 5, 7, 9}

Comment: The `Notation` package method is very nice. Just a shame that, as things are, you must still either type, literally, "`[\TripleDot]`" or else create an Escape alias for it. (Unfortunately, `Esc ... Esc` is already preempted for `\[Ellipsis]`.

Comment: @LCarvalho, did you even test your correction to ensure that it works?

Comment: @J.M. An error occurred while pasting. Excuse me.

Answer (score 2):

The reference page for gives variations which utilize default arguments:

```
Range[20]
Range[1,20]
Range[1,20,1]
```

An alternative for this usage is `Array`

```
Array[#&,20]
```

If you are after a list of numbers, you could use Table

```
Range[6,20,2]
Table[i,{i,6,20,2}]
```

But if you are just using the output of `Range` as indices for `Part` then you might want to look at `Span`

```
f[[Range[6,20,2]]]
f[[6;;20;;2]]
```

Comment: Using the shortcut `;;` for `Span` does make code shorter than directly using `Range` for indexing. But @Sjoerd C. de Vries's method using the Notation package and `\[TripleDot]` makes indexing expressions more closely resemble traditional mathematical notation.

Answer (score 2):

On my laptop I can get the symbol "®" with "Alt-r". So the following code using the infix notation (see [Infix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html)) is very similar to [the answer of Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34418/34008), but much easier to set-up.

```
In[77]:= ® = Range;

In[78]:= 4~®~7
Out[78]= {4, 5, 6, 7}

In[79]:= Range[4, 7]
Out[79]= {4, 5, 6, 7}

In[80]:= 4~Range~7
Out[80]= {4, 5, 6, 7}
```